# How can I make an asp.net button show a popup without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

By popup, I mean w3school's popup javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

I have tried to put the buttons in an Ajax update panel, but for some reason the javascript functions won't trigger.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="footerbuttons" class="questioncard">
                <div class="popup" onclick="savedPopup()">
                    <asp:Button ID="SaveChangesButton" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="SaveChangesButton_Click" BackColor="#F9AF19" Font-Size="Medium" />
                    <span class="popuptext" id="savedPopup">Saved!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="popup" onclick="sentPopup">
                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit to Supervisor" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" BackColor="#F9AF19" Font-Size="Medium"/>
                    <span class="popuptext" id="sentPopup">Sent!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function savedPopup() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("savedPopup");
        eval(popup.classList.toggle("show"));
    }

    function sentPopup() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("sentPopup");
        eval(popup.classList.toggle("show"));
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: both Div and asp:Button have onclicks ?. Try removing the Onclick in DIVs and in asp:Button place OnClientClick="savedPopup"

Comment: Just tried that. When doing it that way it wouldn't trigger the javascript or execute the backend code.

Comment: update    function savedPopup() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("savedPopup");
        eval(popup.classList.toggle("show"));  return false;
    }  and in asp:Button OnclientClick="return savedPopup();"

Comment: So that got the javascript to trigger, but the onclick="SaveChangesButton_Click" did not.

Comment: SaveChangesButton_Click is another JavaScript ? or Post Back method ? Remember a postback will reload the page.. otherwise you need to make Ajax call .

Comment: SaveChangesButton_Click is a post back method. I had wrapped it in an Ajax update panel to prevent it from reloading the entire page, so that the user could see the popup when it appeared, although I have never gotten both the SaveChangesButton_Click and savedPopup to both trigger at the same time.

Comment: No both will not work same time. you should call the ajax function first in your savedPopup and continued by showing pop-up . Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633824/asp-net-webservice-jquery-populate-textbox/42634007?noredirect=1#comment72397320_42634007 for Ajax call sample

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a asyncPostBackTrigger after closing of ContentTemplate tag.

```
   <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SaveChangesButton" EventName="Click" />
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SubmitButton" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
```

then in Code behind

SaveChangesButton button's Click Event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "savedPopup", "savedPopup();", true);
```

and SubmitButton button's Click Event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "sentPopup", "sentPopup();", true);
```